# pass variables between classes

Tags: c#, class, variables, unity-game-engine

I just started with C# recently. I used PHP so I'm not into the syntax yet.

I am using Unity and trying to send a variable between two classes. What I have is a mouse movement and a pause class. In the Mouse class I have a variable called state. If this is true the script runs and if false it doesn't.

What I am wondering is how can I change this variable from another class. Since I was not successful in this, I made a class called vars for trying to make it work. No luck there ether.

pauseMenu.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {
public bool isMenu = false;
public Texture btnTexture;
public bool isShown = false;
public MouseLook mouse = new MouseLook();

// Update is called once per frame
void Start (){



    }
void Update () {
     if (mouse.state== false) {
                    Debug.Log ("Some");
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape) && isMenu == false) {
                    Debug.Log ("Show");
                    isShown = (isShown == false) ? true : false;


            }
            if (isShown) {
                    Screen.showCursor = true;
                    Screen.lockCursor = false;
                    mouse.state= false;
            }
    }
void OnGUI()
{
    if (isShown) {

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 10, 50, 50), "Quit")) {
            Application.Quit();
            Debug.Log("Quit");
        }
    }
}
}
```

MouseLock.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;

public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;

public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;
float rotationY = 0F;
public bool state { get; set; }

void Update ()
{
            if (state == true) {
                    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY) {
                            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

                            rotationY += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
                            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

                            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
                    } else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX) {
                            transform.Rotate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
                    } else {
                            rotationY += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
                            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

                            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
                    }
            }
    if (state == false) {
        Debug.Log ("false");


    }
    }

void Start ()
{
    state = true;
    //state = true;
    Debug.Log ("Started");
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody)
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
}
}
```

Comment: You may get a better response if you post a small example of the issue you are having.

Comment: Instead of some vague description of your code, show it instead. Please show your attempts and describe what didn't work. I also have no clue what this means or what you're asking: `If this is true the script runs and if false it doesn't.` Please note that `C#` is not a scripting language, it is an object-oriented language.

Comment: In short I were just wondering how to access a variable form another class. But I have updated the post. Hope it is what was missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Unity. You must get the instance of the GameObject you are trying to impact. Example, if you have a Hero GameObject with a Hero.cs (Hero Class) attached to it and you want the Enemy to change the hit points, you must either add the Hero GameObject to the Enemy instance such as:

```
public GameObject LocalHero;
```

This is added via the inspector window.

Now you have access to a class in another Object.

You can access the Hero class on the Hero GameObject like this.

```
LocalHero.GetComponent<Hero>.HitPoints = 20;
```

If you don't use the instance by manually adding via the UI, you must use something like GameObject.Find() or similar to get the INSTANCE of the GameObject.